# Ektar 100 pushed to 800 ISO and standard development on High Street

Tags: film, iso, developing, 35mm

If I change the Dx code for Ektar 100 to 800 ISO. Take pictures at night/ cloudy day and then develop it at the High Street studio (without letting them know about ISO), will I get good results?

Comment: What do you consider "High Street"? If you mean your major retailer, SnappySnaps etc,  they'll just push/pull the prints to whatever their automated system considers "normal" - see https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/101574/why-do-my-photographs-taken-with-a-film-camera-look-so-saturated for a prime example.

Comment: @Tetsujin, yes high street = general retailer (snappy, max etc).

Comment: Is this just some kind of hypothetical question, or are you actually trying to solve some problem? Tell us what your problem is - there may be better suggestions for you than simply underexposing ISO 100 film by 3 stops. (The obvious one being to use a more sensitive film and to expose it at box speed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get massively underexposed negatives with very little *density*. At normal settings, your prints or positive scans from such negatives will be very dark.

Your photo processor will probably attempt to compensate somewhat when printing from the negatives or when scanning them, but the results will be noticeably worse than if you had informed them you underexposed by three stops so that they could have ["pushed"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/101082/15871) the development of the film. Once film has been developed, it can't be "reprocessed" the way raw digital files can.

For fuller discussions of the effect of shooting film at other than its rated "box" speed, please see the following questions and their answers here at Photography SE:

[Overexpose film in camera, then push process?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/101076/15871)
[Overexposing and pushing in a roll of film, can they compensate each other?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/71785/15871)
[Film ISO and Push/Pull Processing](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/30251/15871)
[What is push/pull processing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/13786/15871)